# Android development with DB => access database via JDBC (SQLWorkbench) or another tool

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, jdbc

I develop a little application for android platform. So I use the SQLiteDB for storing data. Normally (MySQL, Sybase, h2, ...) I can connect to my database via SQLWorkbench. How can I access to the database at a real device connected USB - debug mode (maybe with JDBC??)?

I'm searching for an easy way to access "my" SQLiteDB at device for at least viewing the data (it would also be great to manipulate data). Just sending a SQL-Command and get the answer ...

It's unbelievable but I can't find any information for this problem at the internet. If my problem is not described clear enough please ask me. :-)

Tia for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I access to the database at a real device connected USB - debug mode (maybe with JDBC??)?

You don't. You have no rights to access the database on production hardware from outside of your application.

One solution is to build a backup/restore feature to your app, and use the backup mechanism to copy the SQLite database file to external storage, where it will be accessible. From there, use any SQLite client you want on the copy in external storage -- I tend to use the SQLite Manager extension for Firefox. If you want, you can also use the built-in `sqlite3` command-line client available on most (perhaps all) Android devices.

If you test on the emulator, you can skip the backup-to-external-storage part, as you can access the database more directly. For example, MOTODEV Studio for Android offers live in-Eclipse manipulation of an emulator's database.

Comment: As a followup to Mark's answer, the MOTODEV Studio database access also works on developer phones (and phones with root access). Since /data/data is locked on production devices, there is no way to access it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is not very comfortable solved at android platform, but copy the database-file to external storage will be a solution to browse the database with SQL-Tools.

Thanks for your help!